# Invalid effective address when trying to copy a byte elsewhere

Tags: string, assembly, memory, nasm, x86-16

I'm writing some NASM code, running on an x86 architecture.

As part of an exercise to write a procedure to print a number as hexedecimal  (the exact details of my implementation of this are irrelevant, as far as I can tell), I need to copy a byte from one string to another.

Here are my strings:

```
hex_digits:
    db '0123456789abcdef'
hex_out:
    db '0000'
```

Let's say I the byte in `hex_digits` at the `ax`th index, to the third index in `hex_out`.

In C, this would look like this:

```
hex_out[3] = hex_digits[ax]
```

And here's my assembly:

```
mov cx, [hex_digits+ax]
mov [hex_out+3], cx
```

Shouldn't this work? Well -- clearly not, but I've read about how effective addresses work, [here](https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/nasm-effaddr.html). After reading that, I was convinced that I understood effective addresses, but it seems that's not the case.

I'm sure it's something glaringly obvious, but I'm fairly new to nasm.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are generating 16-bit code the registers you can use for addressing are limited. If this is for 32-bit code you should be using the 32-bit registers for addresses.

Comment: I'm generating 16-bit code, AFAIK

Comment: @MichaelPetch so, which registers can I use for addressing in 16-bit?

Comment: If you are creating 16-bit code I believe you'll find the answer you are looking for in the question/answer I have marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @MichaelPetch that looks perfect, thanks! I'll test it tomorrow

Comment: Since you’re working with one byte at a time, you should be using a one-byte register, such as cl instead of cx.